# ActiveDirectory Update a user getting UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, directoryservices, userprincipal

When I attempt to update the Description of a user on the Domain Controller, I get the error UnauthorizedAccessException.  I have validated the username and password I am using is in fact able to update the user.  I logged in as the services username and password and manually changing the data.  Here is my code.

```
    private PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Common.DCData.serverName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate, Common.DCData.userName, Common.DCData.password );

    public bool Save(UserData data)
     {
         try
         {
             UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, data.userName);
             if ((data.DisplayName != null) && (data.DisplayName != "") && (data.DisplayName != up.DisplayName))
                 up.DisplayName = data.DisplayName;
             if ((data.givenName != null) && (data.givenName != "") && (data.givenName != up.GivenName))
                 up.GivenName = data.givenName;
             if ((data.middleName != null) && (data.middleName != "") && (data.middleName != up.MiddleName))
                 up.MiddleName = data.middleName;
             if ((data.surname != null) && (data.surname != "") && (data.surname != up.Surname))
                 up.Surname = data.surname;
             if ((data.emailAddress != null) && (data.emailAddress != "") && (data.emailAddress != up.EmailAddress))
                 up.EmailAddress = data.emailAddress;
             if ((data.voiceTelephoneNumber != null) && (data.voiceTelephoneNumber != "") && (data.voiceTelephoneNumber != up.VoiceTelephoneNumber))
                 up.VoiceTelephoneNumber = data.voiceTelephoneNumber;
             if ((data.description != null) && (data.description != "") && (data.description != up.Description))
                 up.Description = data.description;
             up.Save(pc);

             return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Some logging goes here
        }
     }
```

The Common.DCData is a simple class that gets data from a database.  I have double checked the username and password in the database

Answer (score 0):

The static class I created to pull the data from SQL was not instantiated automatically (as I thought it would be) when referencing the static member.  I ended up making the class a non-static class, and instantiating the class manually before using it.